# Firestore transaction summaries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, aggregation

If you have a lot of entries you would usually have a document that sums the price for each transaction. I could read that document to show the overall value in the overview.

My problem is that the price (price * amount) for each entry changes every 5 min. Because of that I can't save this sum value of all documents.

In order to calculate I would need the price I bought at that point in time and the amount.
Thats basically what im saving for each transaction and to save it again makes no sense anything else.

I can't just do a document with one value that I can update all the time because each transaction is bought for a different price and a different amount of this item.

I could have thousands of transactions and the 20k Firestore limit would not be enough for that summary document.

The view for the transactions shows the latest 50 and is paged, that's fine for Firestore but I can't read all documents for the overall sum price.

Is there no other option as reading all transactions? I thought maybe of using firebase cloud storage and saving there a document with all transactions just for the the summary page.

Comment: If you can write the latest information you need to Storage, why not write the same information to a single document in Firestore? That way you'd get realtime sync of that document.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too. Writing all informations redundantly in a single document. The issue here is that the limit is 20k fields for one document and I could save only like 8k transactions like this.

Comment: I could cache it on the client and then its only a one time read off all transactions but still a lot of reads just to get one overall sum value.

Comment: I meant for "the view for the transactions shows the latest 50 and is paged". How about storing those 50 in a single document. It' mean you could cover the first view (and likely for many that may be all they ever meed) with a single document read.

Comment: yes that's true but if someone has more then 50 transactions the sum value on the dashboard / overview page would be wrong. I can't find a solution for this, probably its not working like that. Maybe I should build a custom document paging. Like each document has a sub collection from the beginning and if you get that error that you can't add additional fields you have to mark it as completed and read from the child collection. Just feels like a crazy workaround.